# Syncfusion Essential Studio grid won't start

Tags: angularjs, syncfusion

I have trouble firing up the Syncfusion Grid with angular binding.

What have I done:

- Using http://csg.syncfusion.com/combine, created a JS file with only selected widgets:
  [image: Selection of widgets]
- Included in my angular project the resulting JS and CSS files
- Included also ej.web.all.min.js and ej.widget.angular.min.js from syncfusion distro before widget JS file.
- Went to angular grid demo in Syncfusion and took the following instruction to my page:

  < div ej-grid e-datasource="data" e-selectedRowIndex="selectedRow" e-allowgrouping="true" e-pagesettings-pageSize="4"  e-pagesettings-currentpage="page" e-allowsorting="true" e-allowpaging="true">

and initialized respective $scope variables in my controller.

The grid won't show up. As Syncfusion company did not bothered to write a quick start document on what files are necessary,  I appreciate some help in understanding how to fire them up (with angular support).

Comment: could you please post your full page?

Answer (score 2):

Solved. ejangular module dependence was missing.